# How can I block a keyboard shortcut being sent to a Windows app?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Microsoft Teams uses the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to start a call, and I've set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to open my clipboard history so I sometimes accidentally start a call in a Teams thread when I mean to open my clipboard history, because I hit <kbd>C</kbd> instead of <kbd>V</kbd>.

There's no way to change the shortcut in Teams [yet](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33965626-disable-or-modify-keyboard-shortcuts), but is there anything I can do to block that shortcut from being sent to Teams? I don't mind being unable to start a call with a shortcut key, I just want to stop annoying people by accidentally calling them for no reason.

A system-wide block on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> being used anywhere would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)(AHK) will do this for you. Save this script as a .ahk file, double-click it and it'll load.

```
; Autohotkey script to block Teams from using control+shift+c
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Teams
^+c::
;MsgBox, Bad Teams!
return
```

Here's what each line does:

`; Autohotkey script to block Teams from using control+shift+c`
Anything starting with a ; is a comment so this is ignored

`#IfWinActive, ahk_class Teams`
Only apply this if Teams is running. You may need to change the word "Teams" here to match whatever Microsoft changes the window name to in the future

`^+c::`
Tells AHK to match control(`^`), shift(`+`) and `c`

`;MsgBox, Bad Teams!`
Commented out message box that you can use for testing by removing the `;` at the front

`return` Do nothing when the hotkey is captured

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I had to use `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Teams.exe` instead of the window class, but this is working great now.